# что не так в коде? у меня получается возрастание, а нужно убывание (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, кодировка, случайные-числа

[image: Собственно вот какой код и что по итогу в выводе получается]
и вот как решить данную ситуацию я не могу понять, в чем проблема, при изенении каких либо значений синтаксиса либо ошибка ремува либо просто пустота в сорторовке на выводе

Comment: Для чего `max_number`?

Comment: Код приводите текстом, а не картинкой

Answer (score 2):

Ну так переверните ситуацию:

```
max_number = 0
if number > max_number:
```

Сейчас вы наоборот ищете минимум.

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли))

Comment: @Лафи Тогда отметьте мой ответ специальной галочкой, чтобы ваш вопрос не значился в базе как не отвеченный )  А, хотя не знаю, для закрытых вопросов это может и недоступно... Чтобы вопрос переоткрыли, вам нужно добавить код текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 0):

Хочу тебя удивить, но существует функция сортировки :) работает она как алгоритм с асимптотикой О(n), то есть как линейный алгоритм))
Не помню точно, но вроде она в себе содержит сортировки вставками и слияниям

```
your_list.sort(reverse=True)
print(your_list)
```

Comment: Сортировка со сложностью O(n)!?

Comment: Да, кажется эта работает примерно за O(n log n)?

Comment: нужно сделать без команды sort()